# Performance of calculation of mean squared displacement

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

How can I improve the performance of the following code which calculates the mean squared displacement for coordinates stored in data? Here for each time difference `dn` all possible distance combinations are taken into account:

```
---- distance combinations between points
dn=1: 1 and 2, 2 and 3, 3 and 4, ... n-1 and n
dn=2: 1 and 3, 2 and 4, 3 and 5, ... n-2 and n-1
dn=3: 1 and 4, 2 and 5, 3 and 6, ... n-3 and n-2
...
```

and so on ...

```
data = Import["data.txt"]; (*data file: http://goo.gl/Fmm9fZ*)
msd = Array[0 &, {n - 1, n - 1}];
xSquared = Array[0 &, {n - 1, n - 1}];
ySquared = Array[0 &, {n - 1, n - 1}];

Table[
   dx = data[[n + dn, 1]] - data[[n, 1]];
   dy = data[[n + dn, 2]] - data[[n, 2]];
   msd[[dn, n]] = dx^2 + dy^2;
   xSquared[[dn, n]] = dx^2;
   ySquared[[dn, n]] = dy^2,
   {dn, 1, n - 1},
   {n, 1, n - dn}
   ]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

Is something else possible?

Later on the mean of the arrays `msd`, `ySquared` and `ySquared` is calculated taking into account that of each `dn` the relevant length is `n-dn`.

```
Table[
  msdMean[[dn]] = Mean[msd[[dn, 1 ;; n - dn]]];
  msdStdDev[[dn]] = StandardDeviation[msd[[dn, 1 ;; n - dn]]];
  xSquaredMean[[dn]] = Mean[xSquared[[dn, 1 ;; n - dn]]];
  xSquaredStdDev[[dn]] = 
   StandardDeviation[xSquared[[dn, 1 ;; n - dn]]];
  ySquaredMean[[dn]] = Mean[ySquared[[dn, 1 ;; n - dn]]];
  ySquaredStdDev[[dn]] = 
   StandardDeviation[ySquared[[dn, 1 ;; n - dn]]],
  {dn, 1, n - 2}
  ];
```

My notebook which I used to calculate and plot them is here: http://goo.gl/ztPqxN

**Update for FFT solution:**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34222272/computing-mean-square-displacement-using-python-and-fft

FFT-Code in Python:

1. https://github.com/soft-matter/trackpy/blob/master/trackpy/motion.py
2. the MSD should be done by looking at non-overlapping windows of a given time and then averaging those. There was some recent work (github.com/soft-matter/trackpy/pull/337) to make msd computations faster.

How to get errors (standard deviation of mean value data set):

3. see github.com/soft-matter/trackpy/pull/352 for discussion of computing errors on the msd.

**UPDATE:**

Please use for your code my data file: http://goo.gl/Fmm9fZ

**I am very much interested that the numerical results of my code can be reproduced and that for the whole set of calculations I did (three mean value data sets and their errors) the performance is compared.**

Comment: It might help if you added some words explaining what exactly you're expecting the code to do.

Comment: it is correctly calculating the mean squared displacement of 2d coordinates saved in `data` ... but very slow

Comment: Then I guess it might be a dupe of either [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39105/2305) or [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/100616/2305) whose answers contain code to compute the mean squared displacement. I haven't timed those to see how they fare compared to your implementation though.

Comment: @Martin Büttner: Both answers you mention are treating only a part of of what is physically needed (they do not average over all possible time differences). The upper code has been tested for real particle coordinates and corresponding results are correct and published ... I need just performance tuning help.

Comment: Subscripting is generally thought to be slow and you are doing a LOT of subscripting, but it looks like you are tending to do that along rows. So, can you consider doing a Map or a Table or perhaps even Thread to generate items within each row using far fewer individual subscripts? Or just rewrite it in C and be done with it? It isn't that hard and should be orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: An FFT approach is about 20000 times faster than yours.

Comment: @RunnyKine Can you please post your FFT solution?

Comment: @RunnyKine: I knew you would come back ;-) ... how, did you try it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Update**

My previous code had an error, it should be `Total[#^2] &` (sum of squares) instead of `(Total@#^2) &` (square of sum).
The full code should look like this:

```
data = Import["http://goo.gl/Fmm9fZ", "Table"][[1 ;; -2]];
dx = 1.9*10.^-3; data = data*dx;
meanDisp[data_, dn_] := Mean[Total[#^2] & /@ Differences[data, 1, dn]];
meanStd[data_, dn_] :=
  StandardDeviation[Total[#^2] & /@ Differences[data, 1, dn]];
meanXsq[data_, dn_] := Mean[#[[1]]^2 & /@ Differences[data, 1, dn]];
meanXsqStd[data_, dn_] :=
  StandardDeviation[#[[1]]^2 & /@ Differences[data, 1, dn]];
meanYsq[data_, dn_] := Mean[#[[2]]^2 & /@ Differences[data, 1, dn]];
meanYsqStd[data_, dn_] :=
  StandardDeviation[#[[2]]^2 & /@ Differences[data, 1, dn]];

{msdMean, msdStdDev, xSquaredMean, xSquaredStdDev,ySquaredMean, ySquaredStdDev} =
   Table[#[data, dn], {dn, 1, Length@data - 2}] & /@ {meanDisp,
     meanStd, meanXsq, meanXsqStd, meanYsq, meanYsqStd};
```

> **Update 2** We can further improve performance by exploiting the  `^2` being `Listable`

```
allCalc[data_, dn_] := 
  Module[{diff, x2, y2, x2m, y2m, x2s, y2s, disp, std}, 
   diff = (Differences[data, 1, dn]^2);
   {x2, y2} = Transpose@diff;
   {{x2m, x2s}, {y2m, 
      y2s}} = {Mean[#], StandardDeviation[#]} & /@ {x2, y2};
   std = StandardDeviation[x2 + y2];
   disp = x2m + y2m;
   {disp, std, x2m, x2s, y2m, y2s}];
```

We can also compile this new function:

```
allCalcCompile = 
  Compile[{{data, _Real, 2}, {dn, _Integer, 0}}, 
   Module[{diff, x2, y2, x2m, y2m, x2s, y2s, disp, std}, 
   (* the same body *)
   ], RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];
```

Now if we compare performance:

```
{t, newCompile} = 
  AbsoluteTiming[
   Transpose@
    Table[allCalcCompile[data, dn], {dn, 1, Length@data - 2}]];
t
{t, new} = 
  AbsoluteTiming[
   Transpose@Table[allCalc[data, dn], {dn, 1, Length@data - 2}]];
t
{t, old} = 
  AbsoluteTiming[
   Table[#[data, dn], {dn, 1, Length@data - 2}] & /@ {meanDisp, 
     meanStd, meanXsq, meanXsqStd, meanYsq, meanYsqStd}];
t
(* 
   0.276597
   0.632528
   3.3952 
*)
```

Comment: I have to check it ... the main thing is mentioned in the beginning in my question ... for each time time difference `dn` another number of combinations is possible (it is decreasing with increasing `dn`) and therefore the averaging has to to take into account first all possible combinations and later on for the mean only the relevant existing values have to be used ... (see my update and the available notebook)

Comment: @mrz this is what `Differences` does. Read its docs... I just discovered this function. It's amazing how much faster it is (~100 times than manual iteration)

Comment: I can't believe it ... will check everything tomorrow .. by the way I updated my question concerning the FFT (see above). It is implemented in Pythons trackpy package: https://github.com/soft-matter/trackpy/blob/master/trackpy/motion.py

Comment: I thinks there is a small error: http://imgur.com/8BAX4pe

Comment: To illustrate the difference I plotted your result together with my result: ListLogLogPlot[{msd, msdMean}]. The curves are different: http://imgur.com/kqsAaNF . My curve is the brown one.

Comment: Solved the difference: I replaced your code by  `meanDisp[data_, dn_] := 
  Mean[Differences[data, 1, dn] /. {x_, y_} -> x^2 + y^2];
msd = Table[meanDisp[data, dn], {dn, 1, Length@data - 1}];` and now we get exactly the same results ... may be you can update this ins your answer because this produces the Mean ( x^2 + y^2 ).

Comment: I tested your code example (with my replacement in the comment above) when I want to reproduce all three mean value sets and errors (see my code in the question). Then the performance difference is not much. Could you look again and try it out for all data `msdMean, msdStdDev, xSquaredMean, xSquaredStdDev, ySquaredMean, ySquaredStdDev`?

Comment: @mrz Will try to do it today, I'm still not sure why I don't get the numbers you have...

Comment: `Mean[(Total@#^2) & /@ Differences[data, 1, dn]];` is calculating something different than `Mean[Differences[data, 1, dn] /. {x_, y_} -> x^2 + y^2];`  See my explanation here http://imgur.com/8BAX4pe

Comment: @mrz I found an error, please see my update.

Comment: Great ... we have now absolutely the same results. `Your code is about 15 times faster!` For completeness if somebody needs your code, please exchange it by the following (I used here the same variable names as in my question): http://pastebin.com/MRn00UJ2

Comment: @mrz Done. I also came up with faster solution.

Comment: incredible the performance .. I have to check if the data are still the same ...

Comment: @mrz I checked that  the data is the same between all three methods, and I think you mentioned that the "old" method gives correct results. Regarding further optimization I'm really confident that it's not the limit (I'm not talking about fourier method here). I would say that my knowledge is very limited and the optimization in MMA is often counter intuitive. Also compilation is kinda last thing you want to use, see [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27552/performance-of-compiled-functions) for some examples.

Comment: `allCalc` is indeed about 5 times faster and as you said the same ... wow ... and `allCalcCompile` is even 3-4 times faster than `allCalc` ... so `to summarize your compiled code needs at my computer about 0.12 sec while my old code needed about 29 sec`. This performance increase is impressive.

Comment: I would like to ask you if you allow to upload your code example included in a notebook to github?

Comment: @mrz Sure! Just include a link to this question. And maybe publish link to github here? What about Fourier approach? I tested the RunnyKine's solution and it's several times faster indeed.

Comment: I'd have done `Total[#^2] &` as `#.# &` instead.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an FFT approach for those interested.

```
mFFT[lis_?VectorQ] := Module[{data, acf, len = Length @ lis},
  data = Join[lis, ConstantArray[0., len]];
  acf = InverseFourier[Abs[Fourier @ data]^2];
  acf = Re @ acf[[1 ;; len]]/Range[len, 1., -1.]]
```

This first half gives the position correlation function of the particle. To get the mean squared displacement we still need to compute the first and last time autocorrelation function:

```
msd[lis_?MatrixQ, dt_?NumericQ] := 
 Module[{t, acf, d2, d = Total[lis^2, {2}], ss, msd, len = Length@lis},
  ss = 2. Total[d];
  Scan[(d2[# - 1] = d[[#]]) &, Range[1, len]];
  d2[-1] = d2[len] = 0.;
  msd = ConstantArray[0., len]; acf = Total[mFFT /@ Transpose[lis]];
  msd = Table[ss = ss - d2[k - 1] - d2[len - k]; 
    ss/(len - k), {k, 0, len - 1}]; t = Range[0., dt (len - 1), dt]; 
  Rest@Transpose[{t, msd - 2 acf}]]
```

Here is how to use it:

```
SetOptions[#, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}] & /@ {Fourier, InverseFourier}
data = ReadList["http://goo.gl/Fmm9fZ", {Number, Number}]; (* your data *)
res = msd[data, 1/60.];

ListLogLogPlot[res]
```

Note that you can include the `FourierParameters` option in the code for `meanSqD`, I chose not to. For the provided dataset, it's about 3 orders of magnitude faster than OP's code and an order of magnitude faster than the `Differences` approach. But really, this approach begins to shine when the data is large.

Comment: Form my point of view it is very interesting to see the best and fastest solutions. The speed is incredible ... but, like in my last comment to BlacKow I have compared your and my result: imgur.com/L2gNv9h . Do you know from where the difference comes from?. Are you calculating the mean of `msd = Mean[dx^2] + Mean[dy^2] `?

Comment: I would be very interested if you can reproduce the data I got (see my question above): `msdMean, msdStdDev, xSquaredMean,  xSquaredStdDev, ySquaredMean, ySquaredStdDev`. I got from the developers from trackpy some info, which hopefully helps you: **1.** the MSD _should_ be done by looking at non-overlapping windows of a given time and then averaging those.  There was some recent work (https://github.com/soft-matter/trackpy/pull/337) to make msd computations faster.
**2.** See https://github.com/soft-matter/trackpy/pull/352 for discussion of computing errors on the msd.

Comment: I started a bounty and would be happy if you would have time to look again in your fft solution. I am very much interested that the numerical results of my code can be calculated/reproduced for the whole set of calculations I did (three mean value data sets and their errors). I cannot believe that any other code can be faster than yours. But it is important that we get the same numerical output.

Comment: @mrz. See my update. Check it against yours to make sure it's correct.

Comment: Wonderful ... the same results now. Is it possible to show how you would combine the calculations of all the data sets `msdMean, msdStdDev, xSquaredMean, xSquaredStdDev, ySquaredMean, ySquaredStdDev` (as shown in my question)? I would like to compare the performance of your full solution with what BlacKow showed (may be also for larger data sets). Nevertheless I will later ask you and BlacKow if you allow to upload you codes to github. There are until now no codes for the MSD available which are programed with mathematica. That is very important for Physics and Chemistry.

Comment: I would like to ask you if you allow to upload your code included in a notebook to github?

Comment: @mrz. Feel free to upload the code to GitHub.

Comment: @RunnyKine: What is the reason for dividing `/Range[len, 1., -1.]]` in your first code block. Shouldn't it simply be `/len` instead? What is the idea behind your choice? Sorry I have not enough reputation to make a comment, this is why I need to comment as an answer. Perhaps somebody can alert him about my question.

Comment: @DisplayName Do you understand what division by `Range[len, 1., -1.]` is doing? This is autocorrelation, I'm not sure why you think dividing each block by the same number would be correct.